# How to make valgrind report only errors matching a rule

Tags: c, valgrind, error-suppression

I know how to filter out errors based on suppression rules, but is it possible to make valgrind only show errors that match some criteria? Reverse suppression or kind of whitelisting if you will.

Answer (score 1):

I would start by looking at this: http://valgrind.org/docs/manual/manual-core.html#manual-core.suppress. Which is the first result of a google search, btw.

And something to help create a suppresion file: http://wiki.wxwidgets.org/Valgrind_Suppression_File_Howto

Also, have you considered experimenting with "grep" to filter out only those results you need? If I were looking for specific errors (like array-out-of-bounds), I would grep for those and print them on the console.